# Getting the list of packages of SP2 of Office 2010

Tags: windows-update, microsoft-office-2010

In regards to the SP for Office 2010, I know that the SP is a cumulative package with many fixes/updates etc.

Included in the SP2 for Office 2010 there should be an upgrade called KB2687623. I don't want that update but I do want all other updates. So I want install all the packages included in the SP2 but without KB2687623.

So I uninstalled SP2 but now I want the list of fix included in it to do an hand installation of all other fixes.

What is the best way, is there a way to apply a "custom" update where I can turn on / off specific KB updates or, will I have to install each KB manually?

Comment: Can you clarify the question please? The first item in the list is for Office 2010? Or are you after this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687455

Comment: @daveRook sorry for my bad english. Well, I know that the SP is a cumulative package with other FIX. Included in the SP2 for office2010 there should be an upgrade called KB2687623. I don't want that update. So I want install all the packages included in the sp2 but without KB2687623. So I uninstalled sp2 but now I want the list of fix included in it to do an hand installation of all other fix.

Comment: your English is fine. but I will update your question for you. If you don't like it, feel free to [roll it back](http://superuser.com/posts/640784/revisions).